# Are there different names (or categorization) for methods that operate differently in Python?

Tags: python, methods, programming-languages

So this is a simple question which I couldn't find the answer on the internet so far.

If we compare the .sort() method for lists and the .upper() method for strings, we see that using .upper() or any other string method returns a value that we have to assign to a variable to use in the code. For example

```
my_string = 'Hello World!'
my_uppercase_string = my_string.upper()
```

But .sort() method does what it does directly, without having to assign its output to a new variable.

```
my_list = [1,3,2,5,4]
my_list.sort()
my_sorted_list = my_list
```

*Is there any name in programming lingo to differentiate between these two different kinds of methods?* Such as "Returning Method" for methods similar to .upper() and "Operating Method" for methods similar to .sort() ?

Thank you.

Comment: `list.sort` would be an "in-place" function. There are also in-place _operators_ like `+=` used as `c += 1`. The rest (the regular ones) are just called functions / methods / operators a it's assumed anything that's not "in-place" is returning a result.

Comment: I do not know a quicj way to differentiate the method behaviour. In case you have a doubt, always double check the doc here www.python.org.

Answer (score 1):

In most (if not all) languages that support OOP, there is a distinction between mutable and immutable data types. Immutable data types can only have methods that return a new value. Mutable data types can have methods that modify the object itself and methods that return new values (depending on the purpose of the method, described in its documentation).

Mutable data types can also have methods that do both things (e.g. list.pop()).

Python is no different.  It has immutable data types (int, str, tuple, ...) and mutable data types (list, dict, set, object, ...)

I don't know of a specific name to differentiate these types of methods but the "functional programming" paradigm uses "pure functions" to denote the methods that return a new value without modifying the original data. You could look into the notion of [idempotence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) which is pretty close and could probably apply as "idempotent methods". In OOP lingo, the self modifying (non-idempotent) methods are generally called "modifiers".

In practice, for a mutable data type, you will need to read the method's documentation to determine if it is a "modifier" or an "idempotent method". As a quick rule of thumb, methods that don't return anything are "modifiers" and most methods that return something will be idempotent (with some exceptions such as list.pop())

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly the name but the functions which are performing some operation but not returning any value can be called as void functions.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of this is that this is the high level version of "Pass by value" and "Pass by reference".

`.sort()` is an "in-place" function in python so it edits the values directly and as such you have effectively passed it by reference.

In comparison `.upper()` is a "copy" function so the input to the function is copied and passed by it's value and not the reference to the actual original data.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no other ways than test it or read documantion to know which of the two type of action it is.